# Creating chess like game AI

Tags: ai, strategy, turn-based-strategy

I want to create a AI for chess like game.

Could anyone point me to sources of information what should I know before implementing anything like that.

Some details about the game. There are 5 figures that can make moves and each of them can make a move based on cards that player own. After taking a move card is discarded and player must take another from the deck. Game is won after "king" is taken from the board or king's square is occupied by opposing king.

Any guidance is appreciated :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chess Artificial intelligence with python and pygame](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/77518/chess-artificial-intelligence-with-python-and-pygame) (my answer there is not specific to Python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

[Here](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/artificial-intelligence/chess-programming-part-i-getting-started-r1014) is the start of series of articles that explains making a chess game. It covers how to model the board in your code, and how to tell what the computer what moves moves are possible / viable. Its a bit older, and doesn't provide any code, but it will at least give you a strong start on making a CHESS-LIKE game.

[This](https://github.com/pate/chessmate) is an example of a simple chess game made in java for reference

**REVISED**
What I think would be best would be to rework the chessmate project linked above. First remove the context of piece rank(take out pawns, queens, etc), and then then add them to individual pieces base on something like `Player.LastPlayedCard();`

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged on Stackexchange because they become useless through link-rot sooner or later. It is of course good when you link to your sources or to more in-depth info, but please also sumarize the relevant parts of the information which can be found there in your own words.

Comment: Keep in mind that the game proposed by the OP, is a game with hidden information (each player can move according to cards- I can only assume these cards are hidden for the other player). Also there are decks of cards in play which are hidden information. Thus this is a bit different than Chess which is a perfect information game.